# Volume node affinity conflicts in Argo workflows

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, persistent-volumes, argo-workflows

I have an Argo workflow that has two steps, the first runs on Linux and the second runs on Windows

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: my-workflow-v1.13
spec:
  entrypoint: process
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: workdir
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: jobId
        value: 0
  templates:
    - name: process
      steps:
        - - name: prepare
            template: prepare
        - - name: win-step
            template: win-step

    - name: win-step
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: windows
      container:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
        command: ["cmd", "/c"]
        args: ["dir", "C:\\workdir\\source"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdir
            mountPath: /workdir

    - name: prepare
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      inputs:
        artifacts:
          - name: src
            path: /opt/workdir/source.zip
            s3:
              endpoint: minio:9000
              insecure: true
              bucket: "{{workflow.parameters.jobId}}"
              key: "source.zip"
              accessKeySecret:
                name: my-minio-cred
                key: accesskey
              secretKeySecret:
                name: my-minio-cred
                key: secretkey
      script:
        image: garthk/unzip:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: [sh]
        source: |
          unzip /opt/workdir/source.zip -d /opt/workdir/source
        volumeMounts:
          - name: workdir
            mountPath: /opt/workdir
```

both steps share a volume.

To achieve that in Azure Kubernetes Service, I had to create two node pools, one for Linux nodes and another for Windows nodes

[image]

The problem is, when I queue the workflow, sometimes it completes, and sometimes, the `win-step` (the step that runs in the windows container), hangs/fails and shows this message

[image]

`1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict`

I've read that this could happen because the volume gets scheduled on a specific zone and the windows container (since it's in a different pool) gets scheduled in a different zone that doesn't have access to that volume, but I couldn't find a solution for that.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the first runs on Linux and the second runs on Windows

I doubt that you can mount the same volume on both Linux, typically ext4 file system and on a Windows node, [Azure Windows containers uses NTFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/windows-faq#what-kind-of-disks-are-supported-for-windows) file system.

So the volume that you try to mount in the second step, is located on the node pool that does not match your `nodeSelector`.